# Users behind corporate firwall can't access SSL site using HAProxy

Tags: security, ssl, https, haproxy

I am totally stumped on this one. I recently installed SSL certificates on my site and SSL terminates at my load balancer, HAProxy. So far all of my regular users are able to use the secure connection except for those behind one major corporate network.

Those behind the network get this message in Chrome:

> "This webpage is not available" "The
>   webpage at https://example.com/ might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web address."
>
> Error Code: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

They can access http://example.com site just fine (no SSL) if I enable it.

I was originally wondering if it was an issue with my ciphers, but these corporate users cannot access files on static server either (using AWS Cloudfront with SSL certificate).

I'm guessing the firm may have a blanket ban on SSL certificates unless there is a whitelist? They can access the ssl site of google (https://google.com). Is there something wrong with my certificate? Chrome has a green lock and says my site uses modern cryptography.

Anyway, is there anyway to determine if they can't access my site via SSL and then redirect them to use the nonsecure version? I tried looking through HAProxy docs but am missing something and at this point have tunnel vision.

Thanks to all. Here is my config file:

```
global
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    mode http

    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option http-pretend-keepalive

    timeout client  120s
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout tunnel 120s
    timeout client-fin 120s
    timeout server  120s

frontend https-www
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/example_com/example.com.pem
    #using naked domain
    redirect location https://example.com if { hdr_beg(host) -i www }

    acl is_sockjs path_beg /sockjs

    use_backend sockjs if is_sockjs

    default_backend django

frontend all
    bind *:80
    #How do I detect that the ssl site failed for them?
    redirect scheme https  if !{ ssl_fc }

backend sockjs
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    balance leastconn
    cookie SERV_ID prefix nocache
    server srv_sockjs1 sockjsserver-ip check cookie s1

backend django
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    balance roundrobin
    server srv_static django-server-ip

backend django-nonssl
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    balance roundrobin
    server srv_static django-server-ip
```

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out

It was related to the naked domains. The server didn't like the fact that I redirected https://www.example.com to https://example.com. Upon further reading, I am going to now do the opposite, where I don't support naked domains and now redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

I had to do this on cloudfront too, where I now use www.subdomain.example.com instead of example.com